# How to properly use insert subquery in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a big problem here.

First I have a table `table1` with columns

```
id(int), date(varchar), flavor(varchar), initialWeight(decimal(15,3)), 
liquidWeigh(decimal(15,3)), plusDayWeight(decimal(15,3)), totalWeight(decimal(15,3)))
```

and another one `table2` with columns

```
idFO(int), dateFO(varchar), flavorFO(varchar), totalWeightFO(decimal(15,3))
```

I'm trying to use a mysql command to fill 'table2' with some info from 'table1'.

The info I need is: 'totalWeightFO', but to get that I need

```
`'totalWeight'(initialWeight + plusDayWeight) from table1 (where date = yesterday) - initialWeight from table1 (where date = today)`
```

I'm doing this to now how much icecream I sold yesterday (totalWeight I had yesterday - initialWeight I calculated today)

Its possible to do this? I did this:

```
insert into table2 (dateFO, flavorFO, totalWeightFO) 
    select 
        date, flavor, 
        (sum((totalWeight - (select initialWeight 
                             from table1  
                             where date = '22/09/2015')))) 
    from table1 
    where date = '21/09/2015'; `
```

And it's causing an error:

> Column 'dateFO' cannot be null

I don't know how to solve this. Please anyone help me!

Comment: dates should use a proper date data type; weight would more likely be decimal. You wouldn't normally store derived data

Answer (score 0):

Its not easy to answer without looking at data, few observations -

1. I noticed you are using DD/MM/YYYY format in where clause, by default DB servers dont support DD/MM/YYYY date format
2. Make sure you are actually having proper dates in column. I get a feeling that your date column in table must be having a time component
3. you are getting initialWeight and totalWeight in sum, I am not sure about your data structure but it seems erroneous

Comment: Im doing this program in visual studio. Im storing dates is varchar because   i thought easier to retrieve this values.

Comment: string dataToday = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        string dataYesterday = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()).AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString(); This way im getting both datas in a string so i can compare them, and all the values are decimal(15,3)